# Static resources are unavailable after some time

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jetty, jetty-9

I'm using Jetty v.9.2.10.v20150310, Spring 4.1.5.RELEASE.

I have configured the resources in Java:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/static/").setCachePeriod(ServerVariables.getInstance().getCachePeriodForStaticContent());
}
```

It works fine for several days, beyond that the resources stop resolving.
On the other hand all the paths, which resolve via controllers are stil working fine.
There are no events or exceptions in the logs.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you check what will happen when cache period of time gets finished ?

Comment: Cache period is 5 minutes now (for developers and testing purpose)
It works fine three-five days, after that resources don't resolving.

Comment: try checking where is the caching place in spring stack codes. maybe that's somewhere which is getting intercept by a cleaner schedule bot which is for another application . you get me ?

Comment: there maybe another possibility, when the website is not available for a short period of time, the not available page might have cached so the caching mechanism is ok but the user need to clear his browser cache for caching new available content again

Comment: Mehdi, thank you. I see you point.
I've tried to get resources several times from different PCs and every time Jetty response 404 error.

Comment: ok no problem, have you tried removing the browser cache ?

Comment: I've tried. It doesn't help(

Comment: I've found the root cause. It's pretty simple)

By default jetty unpack war file to /tmp folder.
And this folder was cleaned. So static resources wasn't resolved.